# Does change in n_live_tup and n_dead_tup means that some new rows were inserted into a table

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, usage-statistics

I need to check if some rows were inserted into one specific table. I need to check it on a daily basis.

I've already tried to use `pg_stat_all_tables.n_live_tup` for that, but I am not sure if that works correct and was originally designed for that purposes.

Also do columns `n_tup_ins`, `n_tup_upd`, `n_tup_del` depict if any rows were inserted, updated or deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These statistical data are collected and updated by the *statistics collector* process.
Individual database backends send statistical information to the statistics collector via an UDP socket.

This has two consequences:

- The information is updated asynchronously, so there can be a delay between the completion of a database operation and the visibility of its effects in the statistics data.
- In UDP, messages can get lost.

The information is used internally to trigger autovacuum and autoanalyze, so it does not matter if the numbers are 100% accurate or not. If that is good enough for your purposes, then you can certainly use that information.

Comment: I do not need accuracy I just need to know that something has changed. I'm gonna execute the script only once per 24 hours. I am suppose that if record is inserted, that stat value definitely will get updated within next 24 hours. Also being late for 1 day is not a problem for my case